# Telerik mvc grid validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid

Can this be doable using the telerik MVC grid??

```
Table in SQL
ItemID  Name    ItemQuantity
1       Apple   100
2       Banana  50
3       Orange  10
4       Grapes  40


GRID
Item Name   Quantity        Command
Apple       95              Save
Banana      51 <---INVALID  Save
Orange      0               Save
Grapes      100             Save
```

1. Load all of the Items from the table Items to the grid
2. Allow user to enter desired quantity(qunatity is the only field enabled), but will be able to validate against the quantity in the table before saving. 
   Or create a numeric textbox or dropdown which the max value will be equivalent to the quantity from the table. I'm thinking of using a remote validation in MVC models but not so sure if that would be the best solution.
3. Save all of the items in the grid which the quantity is more than 1 per row or per batch.

Please help me and give me a simple example of this or any link that can be related to this, this is only the simplified version of my very big problem and I've spent more than 4 days trying to do and finding the solution for this requirement. I hope anyone of you can help me.

Any help will be deeply appreciated

Thanks

Samantha

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden column as below to your grid and validate the entered value in the Jquery on save button click

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Items")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.ItemQuantity).Hidden(true);  
    })
%>
```